# Database connection fails online, works on localhost

Tags: php

I uploaded a site on the web and created all required tables in PHPMyAdmin 7.3. Provided required database name, etc. But after uploading it says

> "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/vhosts/rauniyars.freeoda.com/registrations/server.php on line 11"

Same file and connections are working on localhost but not on server.

```
<?php session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '86918');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same credentials as on your laptop, because you're not on localhost anymore. You need to find the db login somewhere in your user area of your free hosting you uploaded your page to. Typically, when you create an account on a free hosting website, they will create the db login for you, you just need to look for it.

When you find it, then you need to change the values in your script which connects to the database (the one uploaded to the hosting, not the one on your laptop).

Comment: i have db login username & password and on phpmyadmin able to log in . so logged in & created the tables in given database. thru ftp cp panel.

Comment: If these are the actual credentials you use on hosting's phpmyadmin, then all you need is the db server to replace localhost. And please, if these are real credentials, don't forget to change your password afterwards.